# how to call javascript and codebehind function on one link button click?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I want to call javascript function and click method on single asp button click event.
I was trying with following code.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSave" runat="server" 
                OnClientClick="myFunction();"OnClick="lbtnSave_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>--%>
//javascript
function myFunction() {}

//code behind method
 protected void lbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So whats the problem here?

Comment: Its calling only javascript function not code behind function.

Comment: did you used any kind of validation controls on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aparna, as you are using validation control than i believe those validation controls get triggered when button is clicked.

To overcome this issue there are two alternates either define `validationgroup` to your validation control or set the `CausesValidation = false` of your link button.

Example

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSave" runat="server" CausesValidaion="false" 
     OnClientClick="myFunction();"OnClick="lbtnSave_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Thanks,Its working. As i have set causesValidation=false, its not checking for validations on that button click, but I want to check validations on that button click also.

Comment: @AparnaRithe, in such case use the first approach that i mentioned in my answer, i.e. define the validation group and on your validation controls as well as link button control

Answer (score 1):

If you want call the js function on client click use this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="myFunction()" OnClick="lbtnSave_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

to call it in a method(codebehind) u can use this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction()", true);
```